# python pulling from json data with the same keys

Tags: python, json

I trying to pull data from a rest API. the issue is that the keys have the same name. I wrote a loop to pull the data into a list, but I know I have the something wrong

```
def getsellorders(coin):
    url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-"+coin+"LTC&type=sell&depth=15"
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    jdata = response.json()
    sells = [0]
    i = 0
    for i in range(15):
        sells[i] = jdata['result']['Quantity']
        sells.append(i)
    return sells
```

Comment: an example url is: https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-LTC&type=sell&depth=15

Comment: You need to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: "I know I have something wrong" -- That's almost always the case.  Even for experienced coders.  Can you try to explain better exactly _what_ is wrong?  (Are you seeing an exception traceback?, etc)...

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: why use a `defaultdict` here exactly?

Comment: @MartijnPieters _"the issue is that the keys have the same name"_

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: the data consists just of a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @user3645405: your sample URL has no value where you put in `coin`; did you perhaps mean to make `LTC` or `BTC` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.append()` to add the entries themselves; loop directly over the `jdata['results']` list:

```
sells = []
for res in jdata['result']:
    sells.append(res['Quantity'])
```

Your code tried to both assign directly to indices in `sells` *and* append the `i` integers you generated. However, the key `jdata['result']['Quantity']` doesn't exist as `jdata['result']` is a list. This all could only first lead to `KeyError`s, then to incorrect data (`i`) being added, then to possibly `IndexErrors` as you assume there to be 15 entries, always.

You can further simplify this with a list comprehension and get all the entries in one go:

```
def getsellorders(coin):
    url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getorderbook"
    params = {'market': "BTC-{}".format(coin), 'type': 'sell', 'depth': '15'}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    jdata = response.json()
    return [res['Quantity'] for res in jdata['result']]
```

I also used the `params` argument to `requests.get()` here to leave encoding the URL query to the library.

I've changed your `market` parameter to actually interpet `coin` as the second part of the market name; your code only would work if `coin` was an empty string.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> def getsellorders(coin):
...     url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getorderbook"
...     params = {'market': "BTC-{}".format(coin), 'type': 'sell', 'depth': '15'}
...     response = requests.get(url, params=params)
...     response.raise_for_status()
...     jdata = response.json()
...     return [res['Quantity'] for res in jdata['result']]
... 
>>> getsellorders('LTC')
[10.0, 1.10799625, 1.4716218, 0.03364621, 0.21046474, 7.05, 0.25586034, 20.0, 22.15658669, 0.19841088, 1.34172574, 0.01096613, 0.399365, 0.205, 0.10813746]
```

Comment: It seems odd to me to have `sells = [0]` in the first place.  My money is on OP wanting `sells = []`, but it's really hard to say since OP didn't specify what output is desired, nor what the input JSON looks like ...

Comment: @mgilson: yeah, I am simplifying as I am parsing what they tried to do.